# Стилизация <select> и <option>

Tags: html, css, style, html-select

Как стилизовать выпадающий список?

```css
.select {
  background: url(images/select.png) no-repeat transparent;
  background-position: 95% 50%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 220px;
  height: 30px;
}

.select>select:active,
.select>select:focus {
  background: url(images/selectactive.png) no-repeat transparent;
}

select>option {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  background-image: url(images/option.png);
  padding-right: 15px;
  height: 31px;
  width: 220px;
}

select>option:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url(images/option1.png);
}

select>option:nth-last-child {
  background-image: url(images/optionlast.png);
}

.select>select {
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 2.5;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select">
  <select>
    <option>
      Language of communication                       </option>
    <option>English</option>
    <option>Spanish</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

[image: SELECT]
[image: SELECT ACTIVE]
[image: как должно выглядеть]

Comment: Вы пробовали искать перед тем как задавать вопрос? Эта тема столько раз уже повторялась и ответ один – на `CSS` никак. Только `JS`

Comment: Корыто прав что option не поддаются стилизации. Но искать на overflow, когда можно спросить? Это же не гуголь какой-нибудь :)

Comment: Есть еще несколько вариантов стилизации select
[введите сюда описание ссылки](https://di-grand.com/blog/css/3338-stil-dlya-select-css.html)

Answer (score 6):

На самом деле стилизовать только с помощью CSS можно. С некоторыми ограничениями, и все же. Для этого нужно спрятать `select` внутри `div`, и стилизовать сам `div`.

```css
* {
  color: #6C7231;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#content {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}

.select-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  border: 1px solid #6C7231;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.select-wrapper:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px gray;
}

.select-wrapper select {
  width: 300px;
  height: 28px;
  padding: 0 20px 0 7px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  appearance: none;            /* remove arrow        */
  -webkit-appearance: none;    /* remove arrow Chrome */
  -moz-appearance: none;       /* remove arrow FF     */
}
.select-wrapper select::-ms-expand{
    display: none;             /* remove arrow IE     */
}

/* 
 * Style #1 
 * todo: try to change arrow DIV to pseudo :after
*/

.select-arrow-1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -9999;
  right: 4px;
  bottom: 5px;
  border: 8px solid;
  border-color: white white #6C7231 white;
  border-right: 0;
}

/* Style #2 */

.select-arrow-2 {
  width: 8px;
  height: 0px;
  background: #6C7231;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -9999;
  right: 6px;
  top: 14px;
}
.select-arrow-2:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  border: 4px solid transparent; 
  border-bottom-color: #6C7231; 
  border-top: 0;
}
.select-arrow-2:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  border: 4px solid transparent; 
  border-top-color: #6C7231; 
  border-bottom: 0;
}

/* Style #3 */

.select-arrow-3 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -9999;
  border: 8px solid transparent; 
  border-bottom: 0;
  right: 6px;
}
.select-arrow-3:nth-child(1) {
  top: 11px;
  border-top-color: #6C7231;
}
.select-arrow-3:nth-child(2) {
  top: 8px;
  border-top-color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="select-wrapper">
    <select>
      <option>Test</option>
      <option>Test</option>
      <option>Test</option>
    </select>
    <div class="select-arrow-1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="select-wrapper">
    <div class="select-arrow-2"></div>
    <select>
      <option>Test</option>
      <option>Test</option>
      <option>Test</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="select-wrapper">
    <div class="select-arrow-3"></div>
    <div class="select-arrow-3"></div>
    <select>
      <option>Test</option>
      <option>Test</option>
      <option>Test</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Пример можно посмотреть тут: http://codepen.io/Eliseenko/pen/bdarGM

Это очень старый пример, можно сделать намного лучше. Что касается `option`, то на чистом css он стилизуется, но не во всех браузерах.

Answer (score 5):

Приведу вот такой пример с использованием `HTML5` `CSS3` и `jQuery`.
Общий суть в том что `jQuery` проверяет наш элемент `select` и под ним рисует кусок `HTML` кода.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Элемент select, который будет замещаться:
  var select = $('select.makeMeFancy');

  var selectBoxContainer = $('<div>', {
    width: select.outerWidth(),
    className: 'tzSelect',
    html: '<div class="selectBox"></div>'
  });

  var dropDown = $('<ul>', {
    className: 'dropDown'
  });
  var selectBox = selectBoxContainer.find('.selectBox');

  // Цикл по оригинальному элементу select

  select.find('option').each(function(i) {
    var option = $(this);

    if (i == select.attr('selectedIndex')) {
      selectBox.html(option.text());
    }

    // Так как используется jQuery 1.4.3, то мы можем получить доступ 
    // к атрибутам данных HTML5 с помощью метода data().

    if (option.data('skip')) {
      return true;
    }

    // Создаем выпадающий пункт в соответствии
    // с иконкой данных и атрибутами HTML5 данных:

    var li = $('<li>', {
      html: '<img src="' + option.data('icon') + '" /><span>' +
        option.data('html-text') + '</span>'
    });

    li.click(function() {

      selectBox.html(option.text());
      dropDown.trigger('hide');

      // Когда происходит событие click, мы также отражаем
      // изменения в оригинальном элементе select:
      select.val(option.val());

      return false;
    });

    dropDown.append(li);
  });

  selectBoxContainer.append(dropDown.hide());
  select.hide().after(selectBoxContainer);

  // Привязываем пользовательские события show и hide к элементу dropDown:

  dropDown.bind('show', function() {

    if (dropDown.is(':animated')) {
      return false;
    }

    selectBox.addClass('expanded');
    dropDown.slideDown();

  }).bind('hide', function() {

    if (dropDown.is(':animated')) {
      return false;
    }

    selectBox.removeClass('expanded');
    dropDown.slideUp();

  }).bind('toggle', function() {
    if (selectBox.hasClass('expanded')) {
      dropDown.trigger('hide');
    } else dropDown.trigger('show');
  });

  selectBox.click(function() {
    dropDown.trigger('toggle');
    return false;
  });

  // Если нажать кнопку мыши где-нибудь на странице при открытом элементе dropDown,
  // он будет спрятан:

  $(document).click(function() {
    dropDown.trigger('hide');
  });
});
```

```css
#page {
  width: 490px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

#page h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  text-indent: -99999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url('../img/your_product.png') no-repeat;
  width: 490px;
  height: 36px;
}

#page form {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 460px;
}

.tzSelect {
  /* ÐšÐ¾Ð½Ñ‚ÐµÐ¹Ð½ÐµÑ€ Ð´Ð»Ñ Ð½Ð¾Ð²Ð¾Ð³Ð¾ ÑÐ»ÐµÐ¼ÐµÐ½Ñ‚Ð° select */
  height: 34px;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 460px;
  position: relative;
  /* ÐŸÑ€ÐµÐ´Ð²Ð°Ñ€Ð¸Ñ‚ÐµÐ»ÑŒÐ½Ð°Ñ Ð·Ð°Ð³Ñ€ÑƒÐ·ÐºÐ° Ñ„Ð¾Ð½Ð¾Ð²Ð¾Ð³Ð¾ Ð¸Ð·Ð¾Ð±Ñ€Ð°Ð¶ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ñ Ð´Ð»Ñ Ð²Ñ‹Ð¿Ð°Ð´Ð°ÑŽÑ‰Ð¸Ñ… Ð¿ÑƒÐ½ÐºÑ‚Ð¾Ð² */
  background: url("../img/dropdown_slice.png") no-repeat -99999px;
}

.tzSelect .selectBox {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /* Ð£ÑÑ‚Ð°Ð½Ð¾Ð²ÐºÐ° ÑˆÑ€Ð¸Ñ„Ñ‚Ð° */
  font: 13px/34px "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #EEEEEE;
  color: #666666;
  /* Ð˜ÑÐ¿Ð¾Ð»ÑŒÐ·Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ð½Ð¸Ðµ Ð¼Ð½Ð¾Ð¶ÐµÑÑ‚Ð²ÐµÐ½Ð½Ñ‹Ñ… Ñ„Ð¾Ð½Ð¾Ð² CSS3 */
  background: url('../img/select_slice.png') repeat-x #ddd;
  background-image: url('../img/select_slice.png'), url('../img/select_slice.png'), url('../img/select_slice.png'), url('../img/select_slice.png');
  background-position: 0 -136px, right -204px, 50% -68px, 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat-x;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.tzSelect .selectBox:hover,
.tzSelect .selectBox.expanded {
  background-position: 0 -170px, right -238px, 50% -102px, 0 -34px;
  color: #2c5667;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #9bc2d0;
}

.tzSelect .dropDown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #32333b;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px;
  list-style: none;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #111;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #111;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px #111;
}

.tzSelect li {
  height: 85px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  /* Ð˜ÑÐ¿Ð¾Ð»ÑŒÐ·Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ð½Ð¸Ðµ Ð¼Ð½Ð¾Ð¶ÐµÑÑ‚Ð²ÐµÐ½Ð½Ñ‹Ñ… Ñ„Ð¾Ð½Ð¾Ð² CSS3 */
  background: url('../img/dropdown_slice.png') repeat-x #222;
  background-image: url('../img/dropdown_slice.png'), url('../img/dropdown_slice.png'), url('../img/dropdown_slice.png');
  background-position: 50% -171px, 0 -85px, 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat-x;
}

.tzSelect li:hover {
  background-position: 50% -256px, 0 -85px, 0 0;
}

.tzSelect li span {
  left: 88px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 27px;
}

.tzSelect li i {
  color: #999999;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.tzSelect li img {
  left: 9px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
}


/* Ð¡Ñ‚Ð¸Ð»Ð¸ ÑÑ‚Ñ€Ð°Ð½Ð¸Ñ†Ñ‹ */

#footer {
  background-color: #212121;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.tri {
  border-color: transparent transparent #212121;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 17px;
  height: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -40px 0 0 -400px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
}

#footer h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -400px;
  padding: 25px 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
}

a,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #97cae6;
  color: #97cae6;
}

a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed transparent;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page">
  <h1>Ваш продукт</h1>
  <form method="post" action="">
    <!-- Мы собираемся использовать jQuery, чтобы скрыть элемент select и заменить его -->
    <select name="fancySelect" class="makeMeFancy">
      <!-- Обратите внимание на атрибуты HTML5 данных -->
      <option value="0" selected="selected" data-skip="1">Выберите продукт</option>
      <option value="1" data-icon="http://ruseller.com/lessons/les805/demo/img/products/js.png" data-html-text="JavaScript + jQuery для начинающих в видеоформате&lt;i&gt;посмотреть видеопрезентацию&lt;/i&gt;">JavaScript + jQuery для начинающих в видеоформате</option>
      <option value="2" data-icon="http://ruseller.com/lessons/les805/demo/img/products/php.png" data-html-text="PHP + MySQL для начинающих&lt;i&gt;купить&lt;/i&gt;">PHP + MySQL для начинающих</option>
      <option value="3" data-icon="http://ruseller.com/lessons/les805/demo/img/products/wp.png" data-html-text="WordPress - профессиональный блог за один день&lt;i&gt;скачать&lt;/i&gt;">WordPress - профессиональный блог за один день</option>
      <option value="4" data-icon="http://ruseller.com/lessons/les805/demo/img/products/joomla.png" data-html-text="Joomla - профессиональный сайт за один день&lt;i&gt;купить&lt;/i&gt;">Joomla - профессиональный сайт за один день</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

Как видно здесь стили различаются от вашего примера, но их вы можете изменить в любой момент под ваши нужды.

Answer (score 2):

Еще пример с [select2 плагином](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage):

```js
$('.js-select').select2();
```

```css
.select-wrap .select2-container {
  width: 220px !important;
}

.select-wrap .select2-container--default .select2-selection--single {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 30px;
  outline: none;
}

.select-wrap .select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered {
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.select-wrap .select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow {
  height: 28px;
}

.select-wrap .select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow b{
  border-color: skyblue transparent transparent transparent;
  border-width: 10px 5px 0 5px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.select2-search--dropdown {
  display: none !important;
}


.select2-dropdown,
.select-wrap .select2-container--default.select2-container--open.select2-container--below .select2-selection--single, 
.select-wrap .select2-container--default.select2-container--open.select2-container--below .select2-selection--multiple {
  border-color: skyblue !important;
  border-radius:5px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="select-wrap">
    <select class="js-select" name="state">
      <option value="item1">item 1</option>
      <option value="item2">item 2</option>
      <option value="item3">item 3</option>
      <option value="item4">item 4</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

С помощью jQuery-плагина `jQueryFormStyler`:

```js
$('select').styler({
 selectSearch: true
});
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.jq-selectbox {
 vertical-align: middle;
 cursor: pointer;
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
}
.jq-selectbox select{
  display: none;
}
.jq-selectbox__select {
 height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
 padding: 0 45px 0 10px;
 border: 1px solid #CCC;
 border-bottom-color: #B3B3B3;
 border-radius: 4px;
 background: #F5F5F5 url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAeCAIAAABi9+OQAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAABdJREFUeNpi+v//PxM2zMDAQEtxgAADAF2uTe9L4getAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) repeat-x;
 box-shadow: inset 1px -1px #F1F1F1, inset -1px 0 #F1F1F1, 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 text-shadow: 1px 1px #FFF;
 font-size: 16px; 
    font-family: 'segoe ui';
 color: #9D9D9D; 
 background: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #3399CC;
}
/*.jq-selectbox__select:hover {
 background-color: #E6E6E6;
 background-position: 0 -10px;
}*/
.jq-selectbox__select:active {
 background: #F5F5F5;
 box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px #DDD;
}
.jq-selectbox.focused .jq-selectbox__select {
 border: 1px solid #5794BF;
}
.jq-selectbox.disabled .jq-selectbox__select {
 border-color: #CCC;
 background: #F5F5F5;
 box-shadow: none;
 color: #888;
}
.jq-selectbox__select-text {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
.jq-selectbox .placeholder {
 color: #888;
}
.jq-selectbox__trigger {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 width: 34px;
 height: 100%; 
}
.jq-selectbox__trigger-arrow {
 position: absolute;
 top: 12px;
 right: 12px;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 border-top: 9px solid #3399CC;
 border-right: 5px solid transparent;
 border-left: 5px solid transparent;
 opacity: 0.3;
 filter: alpha(opacity=30);
}
.jq-selectbox:hover .jq-selectbox__trigger-arrow {
 opacity: 1;
 filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
.jq-selectbox.disabled .jq-selectbox__trigger-arrow {
 opacity: 0.3;
 filter: alpha(opacity=30);
}
.jq-selectbox__dropdown {
 top: 33px;
 width: 100%;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 1px solid #CCC;
 border-radius: 4px;
 background: #FFF;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 font: 14px/18px Arial, sans-serif;
}
.jq-selectbox__search {
 margin: 5px;
}
.jq-selectbox__search input {
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 5px 27px 6px 8px;
 outline: none;
 border: 1px solid #CCC;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAMCAYAAABiDJ37AAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAO1JREFUeNqU078LAXEYx/FzYfNzk5TJaFNKYjFYSQZ/hvwBsvg1UCY2xT9gM8hukQGThWRjkcFw3pdnujhfT736Xn2fPvfc3fd07V0OFDDFAnM0ENYsZRiGLSc9OpqIYIA9fMhhjCrW2h9VlMlcH/aymMGtOqEugX08PwQucUZKdTozMIqdTc9WepQD7wjY9ARx+ydwhfyXfS+S0qMcOEQJGcueB3VccFINdMgal6NzkmPjRwJXxDBB7/2RDdtAp6wb+dpphHDASG5QQ0V6u2aoSqBZD/lDrNWRJynLK2qpBn4rc6K2XB9/Nb8EGABtf1thzY6X2AAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==) no-repeat 100% 50%;
 box-shadow: inset 1px 1px #F1F1F1;
 color: #333;
 -webkit-appearance: textfield;
}
.jq-selectbox__search input::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
.jq-selectbox__search input::-webkit-search-decoration {
 -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.jq-selectbox__not-found {
 margin: 5px;
 padding: 5px 8px 6px;
 background: #F0F0F0;
 font-size: 13px;
}
.jq-selectbox ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.jq-selectbox li {
 min-height: 18px;
 padding: 5px 10px 6px;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
     -ms-user-select: none;
         user-select: none;
      -o-user-select: none;
 white-space: nowrap;
 color: #231F20;
}
.jq-selectbox li.selected {
 background-color: #A3ABB1;
 color: #FFF;
}
.jq-selectbox li:hover {
 background-color: #EEEEEE;
 color: #000;
}
.jq-selectbox li.disabled {
 color: #AAA;
}
.jq-selectbox li.disabled:hover {
 background: none;
}
.jq-selectbox li.optgroup {
 font-weight: bold;
}
.jq-selectbox li.optgroup:hover {
 background: none;
 color: #231F20;
 cursor: default;
}
.jq-selectbox li.option {
 padding-left: 25px;
}


.jq-select-multiple {
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 1px;
 border: 1px solid #CCC;
 border-bottom-color: #B3B3B3;
 border-radius: 4px;
 box-shadow: inset 1px 1px #F1F1F1, 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 background: #FFF;
 color: #333;
 font: 14px/18px Arial, sans-serif;
 cursor: default;
}
.jq-select-multiple.focused {
 border: 1px solid #5794BF;
}
.jq-select-multiple.disabled {
 border-color: #CCC;
 background: #F5F5F5;
 box-shadow: none;
 color: #888;
}
.jq-select-multiple ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.jq-select-multiple li {
 padding: 3px 9px 4px;
 list-style: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
     -ms-user-select: none;
      -o-user-select: none;
         user-select: none;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
.jq-select-multiple li:first-child {
 border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}
.jq-select-multiple li:last-child {
 border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}
.jq-select-multiple li.selected {
 background: #08C;
 color: #FFF;
}
.jq-select-multiple li.disabled {
 color: #AAA;
}
.jq-select-multiple.disabled li.selected,
.jq-select-multiple li.selected.disabled {
 background: #CCC;
 color: #FFF;
}
.jq-select-multiple li.optgroup {
 font-weight: bold;
}
.jq-select-multiple li.option {
 padding-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-form-styler@2.0.2/dist/jquery.formstyler.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="-1">Рост</option>
  <option value="150 см">150 см</option>
  <option value="151 см">151 см</option>
  <option value="152 см">152 см</option>
  <option value="153 см">153 см</option>
  <option value="154 см">154 см</option>
  <option value="155 см">155 см</option>
</select>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/qgm6Lsmj/14/)

Answer (score 1):

Я использовал данный JQuery плагин. Достаточно легковесный и поддается кастомизации.
http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/