# Некорректное отображение тега select на мобильном телефоне

Tags: html, css, select

На сайте с телефона Xiaomi тег `select` отображается так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А с телефона Samsung уже вот так, что не очень красиво:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли задать одно отображение `select` для всех мобильных телефонов? Либо исправить вариант у Samsung.

Comment: Это неправильно, на телефонах самсунг люди привыкли к такому селекту, на айфонах к айфоновскому итд. Но если очень надо, делайте кастомизированный селект. Но это зло, особенно для мобильных версий

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, стилизацию элементов форм в разных браузерах возможно сделать только скрытием оригинального элемента формы, его перерисовкой на html+css и поведение прописать js. Уже вопрос не один раз поднимался на [stackoverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417507/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-select-%D0%B8-option)